# How can I detect if OS is Windows 7 Embedded from an Install Condition?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have an installation package that I want to only install if it is currently being installed on an [embedded version of Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/develop/windows-embedded-standard-7-os-components.aspx). I was hoping to check the WindowsBuild property in my Install Condition, but it [doesn't appear that Embedded OS's are called out](http://www.tarma.com/support/im7/using/symbols/variables/windowsbuild.htm).

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn't have support for this. So you will need a custom action:

- use a [win32 DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx) or VBScript custom action to detect if the installer is running on an embedded version
- based on the result set an [installer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372432%28VS.85%29.aspx), for example IS_EMBEDDED
- use this property as a [custom launch condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Note that InstallShield tends to use properties that start with `IS` for internal purposes, so it may be a good idea to use a different name for the property. (That said, IS_EMBEDDED is probably safe "for now".)